# grep - print file name fails to process

Tags: grep

I Have a logs like this. Which processes number of .bill.file format files. In case of any issues with processing an **SEVERE** message followed by **INFO** will be printed which has detail about file path

```
SEVERE  2016-02-09 00:45:18 [process number] rocessRunner.process Exception during process 123.bill.file
SEVERE  2016-02-09 00:45:18 [process number]
...
...
INFO    2016-02-09 00:45:18 [process number] Runner. Closing input  /var/run/data/123.bill.file
```

My requirement is to get to the path of files which gives exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` is not really suited for a condition based match like the requirement you have but more suited for `awk` which can process multiple pattern match on multiple lines. Here per your input, we first match the string starting with `SEVERE` and when the next match of `INFO` comes, we print the last column which *likely* contains the file you are looking for.

```
awk '/^SEVERE/{flag=1; next} flag && /^INFO/{print $NF; flag=0}' file
```